# Can old flex box wrap?

Tags: flexbox, word-wrap

New flex box has an attribute `flex-flow:row wrap;`
I thought in old flex box `-webkit-box-lines:multiple` will do the same work but failed.
What should I do if I want to wrap contents in old flex box?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this website](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&display=flex&flex-direction=row&flex-wrap=wrap&justify-content=flex-start&align-items=flex-start&align-content=stretch&order[]=0&flex-grow[]=0&flex-shrink[]=1&flex-basis[]=auto&align-self[]=auto&order[]=0&flex-grow[]=0&flex-shrink[]=1&flex-basis[]=auto&align-self[]=auto&order[]=0&flex-grow[]=0&flex-shrink[]=1&flex-basis[]=auto&align-self[]=auto) for the definition of a flexbox based on your requirements. It will automatically generate backwards compatible css code.